# What’s the difference between “how” and “how so”?

Tags: meaning, differences, questions

Please tell me the difference between these two questions:

- *how*
- *how so*

Do those two mean the same thing?

If they do not, please explain with examples.

Comment: What is the context? There is no way to answer the question the way it stands now, because we do not know what you mean by ‘how (so)’; they can both mean many things given different contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that *How so?* is more of an answer than a question and can only be used as a response to another person. It can't be used as part of a wider question, whereas *How* is extremely versatile:

> How are you / How many stars in the sky / How do you make butter from
>   milk etc

Both phrases can be used as an answer to a statement. *How?* is a straightforward request for information:

> How (are you going to do that/go there/meet him)?

However, answering *How so?* implies a slight measure of disbelief or disagreement:

> "You'll never get abroad next year, you haven't saved enough
>   money"
>  "I'm going to get there anyway, you'll see."
>  "How so?"